# PictureBox with SizeMode = Zoom. How get image size in this mode

Tags: image, pixel, picturebox, zoom-sdk

I have Large image in PictureBox with SizeMode = Zoom. How can I get pixel coords from image when I click on PictureBox or how get image position and size in this case? Thanks all for any help.

[View app window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Ldq.png)

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer:

```
double H_or_W = Math.Max(pictureBox1.Image.Width  pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height  pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);

Size NewSize = new Size((int)(pictureBox1.Image.Width / H_or_W), (int)(pictureBox1.Image.Height / H_or_W));
```